# ActiveAdmin - Unknown Column in Where clause - has_many through

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I am implementing ActiveAdmin in to my applicaiton.

On the user model I have the following has many:

```
has_many :payments, :through => :ownerships, :source => :payment
has_many :subscription_payments, :through => :ownerships, :source => :payment, :conditions => "ownerships.buyable_type = 'Subscription'"
```

As soon as I add User to ActiveAdmin I get the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'ownerships.buyable_type' in 'where clause': SELECT `payments`.* FROM `payments`  WHERE (ownerships.buyable_type = 'Subscription')
```

Any ideas?  I am stuck with this one.

Comment: does the ownerships table have a column called buyable_type?

Comment: Yea.  It has that column and all this relationship work fine in the actual app.

Comment: okay, I am not too sure, never used ActiveAdmin, but check out the config file `app/admin/my_model_names.rb` to see if it is calling something else for User other than your model.

Comment: Are you doing any display of the `subscription_payments`? If not it might be a filter on the index causing the issue (see issue [#2501](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2501)).